# Extract parameters from a string and create other factor or logical variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm sorry if I couldn't make the question clear enough. I'm having difficulty forming the search keyword/phrase, so here I am.

So, I currently have a data frame something like this:

```
song.title <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
genre <- c("rock", "pop, rock", "jazz, pop, funk", "funk, rock")
df <- data.frame(song.title, genre)
view(df)
```

Then, I need to convert the data frame to something like this:

```
song.title <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
is.pop <- c("no", "yes", "yes", "no")
is.rock <- c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes")
is.jazz <- c("no", "no", "yes", "no")
is.funk <- c("no", "no", "yes", "yes")
df_needed <- data.frame(song.title, is.pop, is.rock, is.jazz, is.funk)
view(df_needed)
```

The [actual data](https://www.kaggle.com/ashishgup/netflix-rotten-tomatoes-metacritic-imdb) I'm working on has 10.000+ rows, so it's hard to determine how many factors (genres/tags) that should be "converted" to columns. What are my options to transform such kind of data in R? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` option. Here, I separate the lists in the genre column so that each element is in its own row. Then, I simply paste "is." to each of the genre words, as this will be used for column names when we pivot the table. Then, I create a new column with "yes" to note which genres are present for each song title. Then, we can pivot the table wide and replace `NA` values with "no". This solution will work well no matter how many genres/tags you have. The only caveat is that I'm assuming all genres/tags will be separated by a comma.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate_rows(genre, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(genre = trimws(genre),
         genre = paste0("is.", genre),
         yn = "yes") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "genre", values_from = "yn") %>%
  mutate(across(-song.title, replace_na, "no")) %>% 
  select(1, 3, 2, 4:5)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  song.title is.pop is.rock is.jazz is.funk
  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 A          no     yes     no      no     
2 B          yes    yes     no      no     
3 C          yes    no      yes     yes    
4 D          no     yes     no      yes
```

**Data**

```
df <-
  structure(list(
    song.title = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
    genre = c("rock", "pop, rock", "jazz, pop, funk", "funk, rock")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grepl` here for a base R option:

```r
is.pop <- ifelse(grepl("\\bpop\\b", df$genre), "yes", "no")
is.rock <- ifelse(grepl("\\brock\\b", df$genre), "yes", "no")
is.jazz <- ifelse(grepl("\\bjazz\\b", df$genre), "yes", "no")
is.funk <- ifelse(grepl("\\bfunk\\b", df$genre), "yes", "no")
df_needed <- data.frame(song.title, is.pop, is.rock, is.jazz, is.funk)
df_needed

  song.title is.pop is.rock is.jazz is.funk
1          A     no     yes      no      no
2          B    yes     yes      no      no
3          C    yes      no     yes     yes
4          D     no     yes      no     yes
```

**Data:**

```
song.title <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
genre <- c("rock", "pop, rock", "jazz, pop, funk", "funk, rock")
df <- data.frame(song.title, genre)
```

Comment: This seems pretty cumbersome, especially since they said they don't know how many tags to expect

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen upvote for the effort :=)